# How to use ffmpeg on Java maven project?

Tags: ffmpeg, java

I want to use pan control. But I'm confused how to use it.
For example, I can run this command in terminal
`ffmpeg -i wmafile.wav -af “pan=stereo|c1=c1” outr.wav`

How to implement this command in java?

Comment: Can you please post or comment what maven dep did you used to work with Ffmpeg and Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven is also a dependency management solution, it will download libraries which you put in pom.xml.
You can search for libraries here: https://mvnrepository.com/

If you want to use ffmpeg from java, you have at least two options:
find a ffmpeg library on mvnrepository and "import" it, or
use System.Diagnostics.Process.Start to run that command as a subprocess.